# Issue with Setting Up Webpack and Babel

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I have followed every instruction for setting up webpack and babel. I Installed the dependencies with npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-dev-server @babel/core babel-loader @babel/preset-env @babel/polyfill. I also installed the webpack-cli.
Here is what I have in my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "webpack_babel_prac",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "wepack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "webpack": "^5.3.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

The following codes are the ones I have in my webpack.config.js file

```
    const path = require('path');

    module.exports = {
      entry: {
        app: ['@babel/polyfill','./src/app.js']
      },
      output:{
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
      },

      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',

            
           query:{
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
           }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

when I run build (npm run build) it always gives me error:

```
> webpack_babel_prac@1.0.0 build /Users/sel/Desktop/js_course/webpack_babel_prac
> webpack

[webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[0] has an unknown property 'query'. These properties are valid:
   object { compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }
   -> A rule description with conditions and effects for modules.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! webpack_babel_prac@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the webpack_babel_prac@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/sel/.npm/_logs/2020-10-29T18_12_00_720Z-debug.log
sels-MacBook-Air:webpack_babel_prac sel$
```

It's telling me that the configuration has has an unknown property "query" as shown above. When I remove query and leave presets: ['@babel/preset-env']. It will display configuration has has an unknown property "preset". However, when I remove query and presets object it will run build but in my app.bundle.js, the codes from my app.js file are not completely compiled into ES5.

I would I appreciate it if anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [`babel-loader`](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) docs show several examples of how to do this. If you're following guides and seeing this, they must be guides that were written several years ago.

`query` should be `options`.

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',          
        options:{
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks man. I changed it to options and it runs successfully. I will pay more attention to guides next time.

Comment: someone needs to tell about backwards compatibility to the folds who write js libs. It so frustrating!